# How to effectively substitute variables in xAct?

Tags: functions, replacement, physics, packages, xact

I am trying to find the gauge field equation by varying the Born-Infeld Action with the help of `xact` package. I use the following `VarAction` function for this purpose as defined below:

```
<< xAct`xPert`

$CovDFormat = "Prefix";

(*Varying the action: general implementation*)
PerturbAction[expr_, 
  g_?MetricQ[a_?UpIndexQ, b_?UpIndexQ] | 
   g_?MetricQ[a_?DownIndexQ, b_?DownIndexQ]] := 
 Module[{pertexpr, res, dgloc,(*dummyloc,*)hp},
  
  (* We define the metric perturbation, if not defined already *)
  dgloc = SymbolJoin["δ", g];
  
  hp = Head@Perturbation[g[DownIndex@a, DownIndex@b]];
  
  If[hp === Perturbation, 
   DefMetricPerturbation[g, dgloc, SymbolJoin["ϵ", g]], 
   dgloc = hp];
  
  
  Block[{$DefInfoQ = False},
   
   (* We perturb wrt to the metric and if it is the inverse metric we \
put a minus sign *)
   pertexpr = (If[DownIndexQ[a], 1, -1])*
      ToCanonical@
       ContractMetric@ExpandPerturbation@Perturbation[expr] /. 
     Perturbation[tens_] :> 0;
   
   (*We then use VarD. 
   It happens that some trivial Kronecker appear which need to be \
handle manually *)
   res = 
    ToCanonical[(SameDummies@
        ContractMetric@
         VarD[dgloc[LI[1], a, b], CovDOfMetric[g]][pertexpr]) /. 
      delta[-LI[n_], LI[m_]] :> 
       KroneckerDelta[NoScalar[n], NoScalar[m]]];
   ];
  res
  ]
PerturbAction[expr_, tensor_?xTensorQ, covd_] := 
 Module[{res, dummyloc, pertexpr, inds},
  Block[{$DefInfoQ = False},
   
   (* We use a dummy name for the variation of the tensor, 
   and use it to replace the formal first order perturbation the \
tensor *)
   (* So first we define this dummy tensor *)
   dummyloc = SymbolJoin["Var", tensor];
   inds = DummyIn /@ SlotsOfTensor[tensor];
   If[! xTensorQ[dummyloc], 
    DefTensor[dummyloc @@ inds, First@DependenciesOfTensor@tensor]];
   SymmetryGroupOfTensor[dummyloc] ^= SymmetryGroupOfTensor[tensor];
   
   (* Then we perturb the action and replace Perturbation[
   Tensor[..]] by this dummy tensor *)
   pertexpr = (ToCanonical@
      ContractMetric[
       ExpandPerturbation@Perturbation[expr] /. 
         Perturbation[tens_?((# =!= tensor) &)[ar___]] :> 0 /. 
        Perturbation[tensor[ind___]] :> dummyloc[ind]]);
   
   (* With this simple head, VarD works correctly. 
   Again we need to handel some trivial Kronecker *)
   res = 
    ToCanonical[(SameDummies@
        ContractMetric@VarD[dummyloc @@ inds, covd][pertexpr]) /. 
      delta[-LI[n_], LI[m_]] :> 
       KroneckerDelta[NoScalar[n], NoScalar[m]]];
   ];
  res
  ]
PerturbAction[expr_, tensor_[inds___]] := 
 PerturbAction[expr, tensor[inds], CovDOfMetric@First@$Metrics]
PerturbAction[expr_, tensor_?xTensorQ[inds___], covd_] := 
 Module[{res, dummyloc, pertexpr},
  Block[{$DefInfoQ = False},
   dummyloc = SymbolJoin["Var", tensor];
   
   If[! xTensorQ[dummyloc], 
    DefTensor[dummyloc[inds], First@DependenciesOfTensor@tensor]];
   SymmetryGroupOfTensor[dummyloc] ^= SymmetryGroupOfTensor[tensor];
   
   (* Perturbation with xPert*)
   pertexpr = (ToCanonical@
      ContractMetric[
       ExpandPerturbation@Perturbation[expr] /. 
         Perturbation[tens_?((# =!= tensor) &)[ar___]] :> 0 /. 
        Perturbation[tensor[ind___]] :> dummyloc[ind]]);
   (* VarD and removal of KroneckerDelta*)
   res = 
    ToCanonical[(SameDummies@
        ContractMetric@VarD[dummyloc[inds], covd][pertexpr]) /. 
      delta[-LI[n_], LI[m_]] :> 
       KroneckerDelta[NoScalar[n], NoScalar[m]]];
   ];
  res
  ]
VarAction[expr_, 
  g_?MetricQ[as__?((UpIndexQ[#] || DownIndexQ[#]) &)]] := 
 Module[{sqrtg},
  sqrtg = Sqrt[SignDetOfMetric[g] Determinant[g][]];
  ToCanonical[
   PerturbAction[expr, g[as]] + 
    ReplaceDummies@expr*PerturbAction[sqrtg, g[as]]/sqrtg ]
  ]
VarAction[expr_, tensor_?((xTensorQ[#] && Not[MetricQ[#]]) &), 
  g_?MetricQ] := PerturbAction[expr, tensor, CovDOfMetric[g]]
VarAction[expr_, tensor_?((xTensorQ[#] && Not[MetricQ[#]]) &)] := 
  VarAction[expr, tensor, First@$Metrics];

VarAction[expr_, 
  tensor_?((xTensorQ[#] && Not[MetricQ[#]]) &)[inds___], g_?MetricQ] :=
  PerturbAction[expr, tensor[inds], CovDOfMetric[g]]
VarAction[expr_, 
   tensor_?((xTensorQ[#] && Not[MetricQ[#]]) &)[inds___]] := 
  VarAction[expr, tensor[inds], First@$Metrics];
```

The details of my Born-Infeld action, vectors, scalars, tensors and the used metric are as below:

```
dimension = 5;
DefManifold[M5, dimension, {μ, ν, δ, η, χ}];

DefMetric[-1, g[-μ, -ν], CD, {";", "∇"}, PrintAs -> "g"];

DefConstantSymbol[b]
DefTensor[A[-μ], M5](* Vector field *)
DefTensor[ϕ[], M5](* Scalar field *)
DefTensor[F[-μ, -ν], M5, 
 Antisymmetric[{-μ, -ν}]] (* Maxwell strength tensor*)
DefScalarFunction[V](* A potential *) 
DefScalarFunction[f] (*A general scalar function*)

L = RicciScalarCD[] + 
  f[ϕ[]] b^2 (1 - Sqrt[
     1 + (F[-μ, -ν] F[μ, ν])/(2 b^2)]) - 
  1/2 CD[μ]@ϕ[] CD[-μ]@ϕ[] - V[ϕ[]]
```

Now, if I define my electromagnetic field tensor in terms of vector potential as:

```
F[a_, b_] := CD[a][A[b]] - CD[b][A[a]]
```

and then try to find the gauge field equation by varying the action w.r.t. $A^\mu$ by:

```
gaugefieldeqn = VarAction[L, A[μ]] // Simplification
```

I get my answer in terms of vector potentials. The desired solution is:

$$\triangledown_\mu\left[\sqrt{-g}\frac{f(\phi)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{F^2}{2b^2}}}F^{\mu\nu}\right]$$

How do I convert `gaugefieldeqn` to electromagnetic field tensor form($F^{\mu\nu}$) to get the desired solution?